# How to host Facebook app in Heroku?

Tags: php, facebook, heroku, mbstring

I have my Facebook app running without any problem in my localhost. But when I hosted it in Heroku, I got these problems.

The problem is when the user gets redirected from Facebook after login and permissions  it shows blank page, and in Heroku logs it shows:

> "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function                  Facebook\HttpClients\mb_strlen() in /app/facebook/facebook-        sdk/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php on line 300"

I think the error is in `mb_strlen()` function. I do not know how to rectify it.

Comment: I suspect you'll need to enable the `mbstring` module? See here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php

Comment: Actually, Thats the problem...I do no how to enable mbstring in heroku...i can do it in my localhost

Comment: [This search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=enable+mbstring+in+heroku) gave me [this Heroku article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support) - search for 'The following built-in extensions have been built “shared”'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mbstring` extension can be turned on in Heroku using Composer. Just use the `mbstring` dependency and Heroku will do the rest.

I expect it would look something like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
    }
}
```

Of course, if you have other `require`s at present, you should add this to them, not replace them.

Here's [the documentation you need](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#extensions).